How can I determine what modules my SSD needs?
I'm trying to break down a bigger problem into smaller problems so hopefully I can solve eventually.  The offending error is below:
I've done the research to determine that I am using the following drive in my HP Laptop.
SK Hynix - HN8T05DEHKX073 - SSD ( Solid State Drive )

After visiting SK Hynix website, I was unable to locate the drive on their website.
Using the advice from the error I was able to determine that the SSD is nonexistent in /dev where is should be and I don't see any relate modules in /proc/modules
Oddly the live version is working but the list of modules it shows his huge in proc/modules and I can see the correct entries in /dev as well for my drive labeled as sdb
How can I determine what modules my SSD needs?
ChatGPT told me there should be nvme or ahci listed in /proc/modules but I tried to grep them out of the long list and they were not there in the working live file system.
In short I can not correlate what needs to be there and also, I can't determine from the web what modules initramfs needs as of now.
As a side note, I can not get past a captive portal when doing the install, so the install is done with out an internet connection.  I'm not sure if this is what began the issue.  But once again oddly, the live install works and has access to the SSD.  It's just the actual install that errors out into the initramfs.
InitRAMFS Error
Gave up waiting for the root file system device.
Common Problems:
Boot Args ( cat /proc/cmdline )
Check rootdelay=( did the system wait long enough )
Missing Modules ( cat/proc/modules; ls /dev )
UUID = XXXXXXXX - XXXX - XXXX - XXXX - XXXXXXXXXXXX does not exit
c00a3975-a1f2-4f8f-b390-a209c6b3aabe ( per gparted ) /dev/sdb5, ext4

The end goal is to have a dual boot Ubuntu / Window machine.  However the error I posted is what happens when I try to boot into Ubuntu.

Rewind a bit. What's the actual problem you have? You're trying to install Ubuntu? Boot a live CD? Start from the beginning. You're overthinking this as a drive issue. I suspect this is not the place to start. Start from what problem you're actually trying to solve.

The end goal is to have a dual boot Ubuntu / Window machine.  However the error I posted is what happens when I try to boot into Ubuntu.

Is your BIOS/firmware set for SATA AHCI mode or Intel RST/RAID?

What machine is this? What OS is already on it. This question needs a rewrite to actually detail the question you're really asking.

Also, DO NOT trust ChatGPT to give you reliable results when helping you.  It is REGULARLY wrong. (It's why we don't allow AI-generated answers here)

I think the confusing thing is that I have access to the drive when running live on a USB.  That was the main reason testing live before doing an install.  However after the install the installed version does not work or correlate to the live version as I would have hoped/expected.  If someone could provide any insight on to what could cause this seemingly odd behavior ...

Research I've done here on google docs: https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vTlSbg1ecZzSzI9QuJUuRIahRNNZO_7BBLBRDPpwE-uUDgEHWQ8nKknC-n4kEE-wjx6lxRhWscCjYDD/pub

I just determined my drive is a UFS drive so I an rebuild the initramfs with this knowledge, but I would like to know why the correct module is in the live kernel, but not in the initramfs?
